# GraphQL::Client::ValidationError: Type mismatch on variable $id and argument eq (String! / ItemId)

Tags: ruby, graphql

I want to get specific data from DatoCMS so I need to pass a parameter in my GraphQL query. The thing is I'm getting an error:

```
GraphQL::Client::ValidationError: Type mismatch on variable $id and argument eq (String! / ItemId)
```

I'm using ruby `graphql-client` gem to make this requests (probably it's not important) and It's my first time with Graphql.

below my query:

```
query($id: String!) {
  allTexts(filter: {id: {eq: $id}}) {
    title
    isSeparateActivity
    shortDescription
    longDescription
    text {
      article
    }
    author
    _updatedAt
    _createdAt
    length
  }
}
```

If I change `query($id: String!)` to `query($id: ID!)` I'm getting new error:

```
GraphQL::Client::ValidationError: ID isn't a defined input type (on $id)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your query is using `String!`, and it's telling you that it has to be `ItemId`. Without having an endpoint to test it against, it looks like if you use this query, it should work:

```
query($id: ItemId) {
  allTexts(filter: {id: {eq: $id}}) {
    title
    isSeparateActivity
    shortDescription
    longDescription
    text {
      article
    }
    author
    _updatedAt
    _createdAt
    length
  }
}
```